# Session is not working in codeigniter 3 on php version 5.2

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using ci-3 latest stable version . It is working fine on my xammp. But on live server it is not working i checked the php version which is 5.2+ .

please advise me somehow i can use this setup on 5.2.

it is giving me following error.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory

Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 117

Backtrace:

File: /home/content/02/8784902/html/devscript/gallerytobedeleted/application/controllers/Welcome.php
```

Comment: set `$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;` in `config.php` file and check

Comment: already null in config.php

Comment: Okk try to set path as `$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'yourfoldername/cache/';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a folder cache in the project root and set config as

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'cache/';
```

give cache directory write permission

Answer (score 1):

for codeigniter 3

> PHP version 5.4 or newer is recommended.